# UISearchController Cancel Button Not Clickable

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller, cancel-button

There are a lot of questions/answers to this but unfortunately none of them work.

I have a subclass of `UICollectionViewController`, which I want its `collectionView` items to be searchable. I therefore use a `UISearchController` but handle the filtered `collectionView` items in `self`, so set the `searchResultsController` to nil.

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    var searchController: UISearchController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.becomeFirstResponder()

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        navigationItem.searchController = searchController

    }

}
```

I implement the required delegate methods as follows:

```
extension CollectionViewController:: UISearchControllerDelegate {
}

extension CollectionViewController:: UISearchBarDelegate {

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        collectionView?.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        print("searchBarCancelButtonClicked")
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        print("searchBarSearchButtonClicked")
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        print("searchBarTextDidEndEditing")
        collectionView?.reloadData()
    }

}
```

I can enter text into the search bar, filter my collection view and reload it successfully as I enter text. Furthermore, I can click "Search" on the keyboard, which calls the `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` method.

[image]

However, although the `Cancel` button is visible (see above), it does not seem to be clickable. Thus, the `searchBarCancelButtonClicked` method does not get called.

What am I doing wrong here, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to call `definesPresentationContext = true` after you declare your delegate

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    var searchController: UISearchController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.becomeFirstResponder()

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

        self.definesPresentationContext = true .  // ADD 

        searchController.searchBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        navigationItem.searchController = searchController

    }

}
```

Comment: As simple as that. Thanks for your help! :-)